# Multiple submits in a MVC application via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, hidden-field

I have 2 anchor links in my view, on which I am trying to hit the `HTTP POST` method on the controller. The `POST` method has a condition in which it checks value of a hidden field, and on the basis of the condition, it tries to redirect to different views.

Facing a problem that the value of the hidden field is being `NULL` everytime, irrespective of the fact that I am setting the value of the hidden field via jQuery.

Below is the code:

```
<form id="CreateForm" asp-action="CreateForm" method="post" role="form">
    <a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="Submit();" id="finishCreateForm">Finish</a>
    @Html.Partial("~/_Partial1.cshtml", Model.Contact)
</form>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        function Submit() {
            $("#CreateForm").submit();
            $("#myHiddenField").val = "SubmitCreateForm";
        }
    </script>
}

<input type="hidden" name="nameHiddenField" id="myHiddenField"/>
```

In the partial _Partial.cshtml, we have another anchor link, as below:

```
@model Contact
<span>
    <input asp-for="AddressLine1" value="@Model.AddressLine1" />
    <span asp-validation-for="AddressLine1"></span>
    <a id="find" value="findSubmit" onclick="Find();" style="cursor:pointer">Find</a>
</span>
<script>
    function Find() {
        $("#CreateForm").submit();
    }
</script>
```

The controller code:

```
[Route("CreateForm")]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateForm(InputViewModel inputVM)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          //Some business logic stuffs, code removed for brevity
          if (inputVM.myHiddenField== "SubmitCreateForm")
          {
               return RedirectToAction("Test", "Home", new { area = "Shared" });
          }
          else
          {
               return RedirectToAction("Search", "MySearch", new { id= response.Id, type= response.Type, area = "Search" });
          }
     }
     else
     {
          //Some more logic
     }
}
```

I have also added `myHiddenField` in the model coming to the POST action method, as

```
public string myHiddenField{ get; set; }
```

I know I am missing a very basic stuff, please guide accordingly.

Thanks

Comment: @gaetanoM: When I debug using F12, POST method is not hit until the value of the hidden field is set. I mean to say $("#form").submit() doesn't immediately take me to the POST method of the controller.

Comment: @gaetanoM: Setting the value of the hidden field before the SUBMIT code also doesn't help. Any more help?

Comment: @gaetanoM: Did $("#myHiddenField").val("SubmitCreateForm"); as well...value is still NULL.

Comment: Try to change the Find function to         function Find() {
            $("#myHiddenField").val("othervalue");
            $("#CreateForm").submit();
        }
 and let me know what happens

Comment: @gaetanoM: No it doesn't work. Somehow the set value of the hidden field doesn't propagate to the POST method. Very weird.

Comment: @gaetanoM: I put <input type="hidden" name="nameHiddenField" id="myHiddenField"/> in the start of the form. I guess when it was in the last of the form, it was getting re-initialized. Now it works. Thanks

Comment: @Anrug Thanks to you.